# Branch Current changes then "rollback" in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have a specific changeset that I want to "rollback" my Development branch to, but I want to take all of the the changes after that specific changeset and put them in to a new branch. Is this possible in TFS? If so, how could I do such a thing?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. The easiest way is to do exactly what you just said.

Branch the existing code into a new spot.  Then get the changeset you want, checkout the project, and check the changeset back in.

Comment: When I get that changeset though, it doesn't show that those files are changed... would I just need to manually check out everything then check it in again?

Comment: Yes, you do a check out and check the set in.

Comment: Be sure that "Get Latest on Checkout" is unchecked in Options.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Team Foundation Power Tools installed, you can use the command tfpt rollback to create a changeset in your client that will take care of the rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up branching at the changeset I wanted, naming it Development-stable, then renamed Development to Development-experimental and then renamed Development-stable to Development.

Comment: This made me have to do weird stuff, now I can only merge via the command line.